# emulating a shell with commands

Tags: python, subprocess

i am making a discord bot, and as part of the bot, i want to create the option to emulate a shell (allowing the user to run commands such as ls, cd etc on the host of the bot). i tried learning how to use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) from the python docs, and came up with this class:

```
class CommandLine:
    def __init__(self, command: str):
       self.process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    
    def run(self):
       self.process.wait()
       # some processes don't have an exit code, so i check if there's an error instead
       if len(self.process.stderr) == 0:
           return self.process.stdout
       else:
           return self.process.stderr

    def close(self):
       self.process.stdin.close()
```

this class works for running one command at a time, but i can't chain multiple commands that depend on the previous commands (for example, any command that depends on the current directory can't be used because cd doesn't do antyhing). how can i run multiple commands, one after the other, without creating a new subprocess for every one of them?

note: since my goal is simply to emulate a shell, i don't really care about the module being used. if there's a better module or way to do this thing, i would prefer to use that

Comment: This is difficult to do. You'll need to create an interactive shell subprocess without waiting for it to exit. You can send each command to its stdin, and read from its stdout. But there's no easy way to tell when the command is done. You could use `pexpect` and wait for the next command prompt, but you need to know what the prompt looks like.

Answer (score 0):

not the best solution for every case, but i decided to instead run every command alone, and create functions for anything that effects the system itself:

```
class CommandLine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dir = os.getcwd()
    
    def run(self, command: str):
        result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True)
        if len(result.stderr) == 0:
            return result.stdout
        else:
            return result.stderr
    
    def cd(self, new: str):
        # here should be the code for the cd command
        ...
```

i am aware that this is not the best solution, since i need to create a new function for every command that i want to use, but it does the job, and since this is just a small discord bot, i don't mind this.